# What to do with comments that imply wrong answers?

Tags: discussion, comments

On a number of questions, I have seen comments that seem of low if any scientific value.

- [Difference-in-Difference on State Sales Tax Rates](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5720/difference-in-difference-on-state-sales-tax-rates)
- [How does the core relate to strong equilibrium?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5525/how-does-the-core-relate-to-strong-equilibrium/5705#5705)

How to deal with such comments, that in both cases seem to get the OP mistaken about his original question? In the second case, it was possible to formulate an answer that hopefully could levy the ambiguity, but in the first case, it's just comment vs comment, with no possibility to downvote.

*I'm having a hard try figuring out whether to close this question or not. I don't believe the burden of proof, resisting trolls or whatever should lie on new users and people with dim knowledge of economics, and the issue I wish to adress here goes beyound trolling. However, I'm sceptic about my ability to fight trolls under the bemused eye of trolls themselves...*

Comment: The first case is an issue, but not a frequent one. So far, it has only happened to me with exactly that user, who has been trolling throughout several questions/answers. I decided for my own mental health to not interact any more.

Comment: @Foobar I would love to do so, but I'm afraid we'll leave a large number of credulous users following his credible yet false reasoning...

Answer (score 2):

I guess one way would be to forbid these kind of comments. They're not clarifying anyways, but rather attempts at answering the question.

Hence, forbid these type of comments but allow them only as answers, and hope that voting results correspond to the truth [tm]

Comment: Am I allowed to accept this kind of answers on meta?

Comment: I don't think accepting it "means" anything. Upvotes imply agreement, down votes disagreement. If there is a highly up voted answer, moderators typically take that into account when setting up "guidelines".